# Undefined index: commerce_product in views_handler_field_field->query()

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce

I build a website with Drupal Commerce. After I add a product to the cart and I consult the shopping cart, which is empty. I get this message:

> Notice: Undefined index: commerce_product in views_handler_field_field->query() (line 188 of /var/www/jkbudosport/sites/all/modules/views/modules/field/views_handler_field_field.inc).
>   Notice: Undefined index: entity keys in views_handler_field_field->query() (line 200 of /var/www/jkbudosport/sites/all/modules/views/modules/field/views_handler_field_field.inc).

Comment: Please show some relevant code (especillay the lines mentioned in the error)

Comment: You are probably using PHP code on a view without checking variables for existence, ie, `if(!empty($foo['bar'])){/*...*/}`, I +1'd RedBaron comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this issue can be caused by a permission issue, as explained also in [issue #2008820](https://www.drupal.org/node/2008820#comment-9774049) of the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) issue queue, and which states:

> This was a permissions issue.
>
> Someone had disabled permissions, Access was set to none. I reset
>   Access to be role based for admin users and these errors are now gone
>   and the view is rendering properly.